# hashkey mismatch error android faebook app

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

i created a react native android app. and then was using react-native-fbsdk to authenticate user using facebook..t i have registered the app in facebook developer portal and changed my manifest file and string file. when i launch the LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']) it authenticates and brings me to facebook, signs in and then gives me error "The key hash does not match any stored key hashes. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android for more information.".
i have created the hashkey with teh command in the help documenation with both the options here:
1.
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | C:\Users\manshuk\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\Users\manshuk\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl base64

2. and using the debug.keystore of the app itself like this:
   keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore android/app/debug.keystore  | C:\Users\manshuk\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\Users\manshuk\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl base64

i added the key in the app in facebook. in app setting, facebook.

Comment: there is a hash key displayed when the above error appears. have you added it to the developer portal?

Comment: nothing appears above the error message. i saw some people said that in some other forums too but in my case there is no hash key appearing before that message

Comment: i tried to run it again today and i did got the hash in the error message which i added in FB and it worked. still dont understand why it did not work yesterday. clearly my hash is not the same that got sent earlier. this makes me wonder what will happen when i am ready to publish the app on playstore.

Answer (score 0):

Im not saying this works all the time. But, this worked for me.

First get you sha-1 (**Read the code**, youll have to  **EDIT** it)

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\EDIT THIS\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

paste that in your Command prompt.

Now copy your sha-1

GO HERE > https://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php

Paste your sha-1 key in the "**HEX STRING:**"

Copy the value of **Output (base64):**

Now paste that in your fb developer app hash keys

Save, delete your app in your phone, re-install, run.

Comment: tried this but it did not work for me. although now i see error message has hash and when i add that hash key it works for me.